# sails.js - layout could knows the controller/view called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, layout, view, sails.js

Is there a way with the sails.js framework to know from a layout what is the controller/action called?

I mean, is it binded automatically into some kind of variables accessible from ejs? Or I have to bind it manually by passing the values to the view when I call it from the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `req` object is available in your layout, so you can examine `req.target` in v0.9.8 to get the name of the controller/action, or `req.options` in v0.10.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there was a 0.10, will take a look!

Comment: v0.10 isn't released yet, just future-proofing my answer :)